# Unresolved reference for composite builds in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a KMP project with dependencies to 3 other KMP library projects. I am adding them as dependencies in the build.gradle to sourceSets -> commonMain -> dependencies like this( after adding the path to the settings.gradle with `includeBuild`):

```
implementation "net.test:libraryA"
implementation "net.test:libraryB"
implementation "net.test:libraryC"
```

Until Kotlin 1.4 i didn't have any problem with this approach. With 1.4 **the project is still building** but the imports of the dependencies after the first one (libraryB  and libraryC in this case) are always showing **Unresolved reference** errors in the **IntelliJ**. So basically any local KMP library that i add as a dependency after the first one is showing the same error.

I updated the Kotlin version to 1.4.10 and the Gradle version to 6.3 also I tried invalidate caches/restart with the IDE ( IntelliJ 2020.2.3 Community Edition) but still having the same issues. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64838634/android-studio-4-1-kotlin-11-4-20-rc-incorrect-import-syntax-error-display - did you trying adding this flag? `kotlin.mpp.enableGranularSourceSetsMetadata=true`

Comment: I don't have the `Unresolved reference` errors anymore but when i want to go to the definition/declaration of a class from libraryB or libraryC it shows the "IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file" not the class itself. For libraryA it still shows the actual class declaration

Comment: `it shows the "IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file" not the class itself.` How do you configure dependency on this library? For it to be resolved to the source code from module - the dependency must be added as a project dependency:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:project_dependencies If problem remains, please provide a sample project.

Comment: First I add the libraryA,B,C path with the `includeBuild` in settings.gradle file( e.g `includeBuild "../libraryB"`). Then i add the dependencies as  described in the main post to sourceSets -> commonMain -> dependencies. This approach worked perfectly untill Kotlin 1.4 update

Comment: Hello, @koraxis, could you please edit the question to illustrate the current state of the problem?